# Is it possible to add more than one AWS ACL to a subnet?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, acl, amazon-vpc

I currently have hit the max number of entries in my existing AWS Access Control List (ACL). Every couple of weeks a few new IPs try to attack my servers and I am unable to add any more "DENY" entries to prevent it.

Is it possible to create a new ACL and also attach it to the VPC subnet in addition to the current full ACL? Or would this just void the existing ACL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot attach multiple ACLs to a single subnet. If you create an ACL and attach it to the subnet it will override the existing ACL.

You can request AWS Support to increase Rules per ACL limit up to the maximum of 40 rules/ACL (default 20 rules/ACL). If you already crossed the maximum limit, you can use Iptables or Windows Firewall to block the traffic from attackers.

- [Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Appendix_Limits.html)

Hope this helps.